# Planetary phase angle of Hohmann transfer

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite

This is Question 23 from USAAAO First Round 2015. The answer is D. Can someone show how to get the answer?

> Calculate the planetary phase angle (counterclockwise from Earth, a =
> 1.0 AU) that a probe may correctly complete a Hohmann transfer orbit to Venus (a = 0.7 AU)
>
> - a. 141 degrees
> - b. 17.5 degrees
> - c. 121 degrees
> - d. 241 degrees
> - e. 343 degrees

What I tried:

- Semimajor axis of Hohmann orbit: 0.85 AU
- Period of Hohmann orbit: 0.7836 yr
- Time of flight: 0.3918 yr
- Period of Venus: 0.5856 yr
- Angular distance travelled by Venus during flight: 241°

The last one looks suspiciously similar to the answer, but using that angular distance the phase angle should be 61°. Feel free to correct me anywhere that I’m wrong

[image: Phase angle=61°][image: Phase angle=48.99°]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  It seems to be "Here is a test question. The answer is D. I did some working and I got D.  Please tell me what I did right." That is sort of an odd question to ask.  Could you clarify.

Comment: I think the question here is why is the angular distance Venus travelled in that time the answer

Comment: James K,  thanks for replying. I have added a diagram to show what I thought of the question.

Comment: In the first diagram, the phase angle is 61°. In the second, it is 49°

Comment: Both of your diagrams appear to be incorrect. There's no need for the fourth unlabeled object, and the Earth-Sun-Venus path should not be a straight line.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks for replying. It would be great if you can show us the correct diagram.

Comment: @DavidHammen - I think the fourth object is supposed to be Venus at the initial time (given it's the same colour as the labelled Venus)

Comment: I edited the images just for readability (I couldn't read them easily as they were so huge) - if you think it causes issues please revert.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that Earth and Venus have circular, coplanar orbits.
The spacecraft advances 180° in heliocentric ecliptic longitude in 143 days; meanwhile, Venus advances 241° and Earth advances 141°.
When the spacecraft departs from Earth (left), Venus should be 61° behind Earth as seen from the Sun.
When the spacecraft arrives at Venus (right), Venus should be 39° ahead of Earth.

[image: Earth-Venus departure and arrival]

The Sun-Earth-Venus angle marked in green in your second figure is Venus's elongation, 43° east of the Sun as seen from Earth at departure time.

In another context, "phase angle" could refer to the Sun-Venus-Earth angle.
At departure time, an Earth-based observer would see Venus in a 76° phase angle or 62% illuminated.

Comment: Which means the USAAAO got it wrong when setting the question.